# Non-dimensionalization and the functional form of the variables

Tags: dimensional-analysis

**Problem**

In performing non-dimensionalization, I often get confused about the functional form of the dependence of one quantity on other variables. As a basic example, imagine a physical variable $\phi(x)$; one can obtain the dimensionless form by dividing this by a  constant $\phi_0$, i.e. $\phi^*(x) = \phi(x)/\phi_0$. However, when $x$ needs to be non-dimensionalized, things get confusing: $\phi^*(x_0 x^*)$ is the dimensionless variable, but there are still dimensionful parameters in its arguments. In many textbooks,  it's often simply written as $\phi^*(x^*)$ and that is what confuses me. How can one make sure the new (functional) form of the physical variable (here $\phi^*$) can be written as a function of  the dimensionless variables only, and does not depend on any of the dimensionful quantities?

below I give details about a similar issue in the context of noisy diffusion equations.

**Detailed Example**

Consider a noisy Burger's equation:
\begin{align}
\partial_t \phi (\mathbf{r},t) = \nu\nabla^2 \phi + \eta(\mathbf{r},t),\qquad\qquad \left\langle \eta(\mathbf{r},t) \eta(\mathbf{r}',t') \right\rangle = -2 D \delta(t-t')\nabla^2\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}').
\end{align}

I am trying to understand what is exactly meant by nondimensionalizing this equation. So assume I set
\begin{align}
t^* = t/t_0, \quad \mathbf{r}^* = \mathbf{r}/\ell, \qquad  \phi^* = \phi/\phi_0,
\end{align}
then I get
\begin{equation}
\partial_{t^*} \phi^*(\ell \mathbf{r}^*, t_0t^*) = \left( \frac{t_0 \nu}{\ell^2}\right) {\nabla^*}^2\phi^* + \left(\frac{t_0}{\phi_0}\right) \eta(\ell \mathbf{r}^*,t_0 t^*), \qquad\qquad 
\left\langle \eta(\ell\mathbf{r}^*,t_0 t^*) \, \eta(\ell {\mathbf{r}'}^*,{t'}^*) \right\rangle = -2 \left(\frac{D}{t_0 \ell^5} \right) \delta(t^*-{t'}^*) {\nabla^*}^2 \delta(\mathbf{r}^*-{\mathbf{r}'}^*)
\end{equation}

Now Imagine I choose $(t_0\nu=\ell^2)$ and define $\eta^* = (t_0/\phi_0)\eta$ and $\mathcal{D} =(t_0 D)/(\phi_0^2 \ell^5)$. These give
\begin{equation}
\partial_{t^*} \phi^* (\ell\mathbf{r}^*,t_0t^*) = {\nabla^*}^2\phi^* +\eta^*(\ell\mathbf{r}^*,t_0t^*), \qquad\qquad \left\langle \eta^*(\ell\mathbf{r}^*,t_0 t^*) \, \eta^*(\ell {\mathbf{r}'}^*,{t'}^*) \right\rangle = -2 \mathcal{D} \delta(t^*-{t'}^*) {\nabla^*}^2 \delta(\mathbf{r}^*-{\mathbf{r}'}^*)
\end{equation}

**Questions**

1. How can I obtain the dimensionless equation where the variables are only a function of the dimensionless variables? For example:
   \begin{equation}
   \partial_{t^*}\varphi(\mathbf{r}^*,t^*) = {\nabla^*}^2\varphi + \xi(\mathbf{r}^*,t^*)
   \end{equation}
2. Is there a general way of obtaining such equations for a general problem? For a problem with only one dimensionless parameter, one could argue that the value of that parameter can be set to 1, and it possibly means the functional form of the variables will remain unchanged. What about a problem with many dimensionless parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You've already done the hard work.

1. You can just define $\varphi({\bf r^*},t^*)=\phi(\ell {\bf r^*},t_0 t^*)$ and $\xi({\bf r}^*,t)= \eta( \ell {\bf r}^*,t_0 t^*)$. Then your equation becomes

$$\partial_{t^*} \varphi({\bf r}^*, t^*)= \left(\frac{t_0 \nu}{\ell^2} \right)\nabla^{*2} \varphi({\bf r}^*, t^*) + \left( \frac{t_0}{\phi_0} \right) \xi({\bf r}^*,t).$$

Now you can solve your PDE for $\varphi({\bf r}^*, t^*)$ with your favourite method. Then you know how the original dimensionful function is related to the dimensionless one and recover that. *E.g.*, if $\varphi$ vanishes at ${\bf r}^* =1$, then $\phi$ vanishes at $\ell {\bf r}^*= \ell$, *etc*...

2. You don't need to set the parameter to 1 and, in general, it won't be equal to 1. You can arrive at a dimensionless version in the approach you have outlined + the extra step that I explained in (1.).

Comment: Yes, I see. But then $\varphi$ is not only a function of $(\mathbf{r}^*, t^*)$ but also depends on $\ell$ and $t_0$ right? Also, does $\varphi$ necessarily 'look like' $\phi$?

Comment: Nothing in the real world is only a function of 2 variables anyways. It's a model used to simplify so that we can give simple answers to questions. And yes, $\varphi$ does look like $\phi$ up to a rescaling of the two axes ${\bf r}$ and $t$. You can always recover one from the other by doing just that.

Comment: @dedekindCuttage The point is that you can think of it as a function of only those two parameters and solve for it. You can reintroduce the parameters again later when you want to find $\phi$.

Comment: I guess $\varphi$ could in principle be a function of all the dimensionless parameters that  can be constructed in the theory (not $\ell$ and $t_0$ because they are dimensional), but then I can't see how it means $\varphi$ looks the same as $\phi$

Comment: @dedekindCuttage Not the same, but up to a rescaling. Imagine you solve for $\varphi$ and plot it with the two axes ${\bf r}^*$ and $t^*$. Now keep the *exact same plot* but rename the axes to $\ell {\bf r}^*$ and $ t_0 t^*$ and you have the solution for $\phi(\ell {\bf r}^*, t_0 t^*)= \phi({\bf r},  t)$, which is the solution to your original system.